# Crystal Report: Export to PDF , parameter value missing in report in asp .net

Tags: crystal-reports-8.5

I have designed a crystal report using a stored proc which takes two datetime parameter.
I put these two parameters in report header and when I run the report by providing parameter value it shows the data appropriately with the parameter value in report header.
But i am facing problem when i try to use this crystal report to export to PDF in a asp .net web application . I set a dataset to ReportDocument object's SetDataSource() function and the data is populating correctly **but the parameter value not showing in report header.** as it required to show the date range of reporting.

I did the following code to export to PDF. I did not used any ReportViewer as I just want to save or open the pdf file in a new window . For this i just did the following code in button click event and the data comes correctly but the parameter value is missing in report header.
Plz help..

```
    protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ParameterDiscreteValue dateFrom = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
        dateFrom.Value = DateTime.Parse(txtDateFrom.Text.ToString());

        ParameterDiscreteValue dateTo = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
        dateTo.Value = DateTime.Parse(txtDateTo.Text.ToString());

        ReportDocument pdfReport = new ReportDocument();

        pdfReport.Load(Server.MapPath(@"rptClearingChargeBranchWiseHV.rpt"));

        reportName = "Report" + DateTime.Today.Year.ToString() +
                             DateTime.Today.Month.ToString() + DateTime.Today.Day.ToString();

        pdfReport.SetDatabaseLogon("user", "pass", "server", "DataBase");
        pdfReport.Database.Tables[0].SetDataSource(GetData().Tables[0].DefaultView);
        //GetData() return the data set
        pdfReport.SetParameterValue("@DateFrom", dateFrom);
        pdfReport.SetParameterValue("@DateTo", dateTo);

        pdfReport.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, true, reportName);
        Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: Hello experts ..please come to this problem and help...